# Dashboard icon classification lose efficacy after restart

Tags: icons, ubuntu-gnome

I can drag the icon together to classify the same applications that  effectivem, however once I cut off the power, everything got disarranged, and the classification folder disappeared. This phenomenon appeared after I changed my username, the name of my home folder. What can I do?. I already had reference GNOME's documentation about AppFolders "https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/AppFolders" and I tried to create an AppFolder by following the steps in the documentation, but nothing happened to it.

- Ubuntu version :22.04
- GNOME version :42.5

Overview after manual classify:

[image: overview after manual classify]

Restart after cut off power:

[image: restart after cut off power]